# Axios GET request returning empty object

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express, axios

The 'getData' function in the 'dataService' class performs a GET request to the API and the console.log in the 'updateData' function does print the right information but an empty object is returned for 'http://localhost:xxxx/api/data'. I think it is due to a problem with asynchronous but I can't figure out how to fix it. Any ideas?

dataService.ts:

```
import { Format } from '../types';

import axios from 'axios';


const token = process.env.TOKEN;

const url = `https://www.something.com/somequery?someapikey=${token}`;

const getData = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get<Format>(url);
    return response.data;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
};

const updateData = async (): Promise<Format | undefined> => {
  const allData = await getData();
  console.log(allData, 'allData in backend');
  //edit allData to suitable format here
  return allData;
};

export default {
  updateData
};
```

data.ts:

```
import express from 'express';
import dataService from '../services/dataService';

const router = express.Router();

router.get('/', (_req, res) => {
  res.send(dataService.updateData());
});

export default router;
```

index.ts:

```
import express from 'express';
const app = express();

...

import dataRouter from './routes/data';

...

app.use(express.json());

...

app.use('/api/data', dataRouter);

...
```

Comment: try to log the response object in getData function

Comment: Logging response.data in 'getData' prints the same output as logging allData in 'updateData'. In the order: response.data first, allData second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix `getData` to return Promise, resolved one when success and rejected one when not.

When you have async function it is expected to return promise especially when you want to `await` it.

```
const getData = async () => {
 try {
    const response = await axios.get<Format>(url);
    return Promise.resolve(response.data);
 } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    return Promise.reject()
   }
};`
```

Also the updatr data shall resilve promise

```
const updateData = async (): Promise<Format | undefined> => {
const allData = await getData();
console.log(allData, 'allData in backend');
//edit allData to suitable format here
return Promise.resolve(allData);
};
```

You need also to wait for the updateData :

```
import express from 'express';
import dataService from '../services/dataService';

const router = express.Router();

router.get('/', (_req, res) => {
  dataService.updateData()
   .then(data=>{
     res.send(data)
    })
   .catch(error=>{})
 
 });

export default router;
```

Comment: Thank you for your message! This doesn´t seem to work. It gives me the same result.

Comment: @kcin when console.log(response.data) you see data ?

Comment: Yes. Logging response.data in 'getData' after "const response = await axios.get<Format>(url);" prints the same output as logging allData in 'updateData'. In the order: response.data first, allData second.

Comment: Ok i understand the issue now. Updated the answer

Comment: I did dataService.updateData()
   .then(data=>{
     res.send(data)
    }) and that worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`Response.send` should receive the resolved value from `updateData()`, not the returned value from it since returned value of an async function is a promise object, add missing await will solve the problem:

```
res.send(await dataService.updateData());
```

Comment: Thank you for your message! For some reason I couldn't like your answer but I'll try it.